# Sharepoint 2010 Adjusting lists limits to recomendations

Tags: splistitem, content-database, spfield, limitations

I have huge list, which has too much fields of same type (e.g., Date and Time fields limit in list is 8, of that type I have way more). If those those limits are exceeded, list item data will be saved in data table using few records.  So I tried to change types for fields (e.g., Date and Time to Single line text) so all field types would be within limits. But after checking data in the database I saw that the row count for list item didn't change. So, from this problem I have few questions:

1) How to update database after removing fields which are over limit? because even if i don't break the limit anymore, extra rows are still kept and being created with new list items.

2)Do list's field types have to share column count in table if they use same type database column?

3) Do SharePoint fields like 'Modified' or 'Created by' are included in limitations of field types?